# Xamarin image and buttons

Tags: xamarin

I am developing an app and I am still new to it.

I want to develop an app that functions like the London underground tunnel app, you have an image and depending on where you tap on the image different details will popup.

I did try using flutter to get global position of the tap, it only works if the image is not zoomed in, as soon as you zoom the location is different.

Is there any way (using xamarin) that i can add buttons on images? I still need to zoom in on the image and tap certain locations?

Regards

Comment: could you show the effect ？

Comment: if this a static image may be, but to be very honest I think its better done natively than using a cross-platform approach